# Drawing this diagram in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I'm trying to draw above image. What I've got so far is:

[image]

Not very close. I'm struggling in leveling outer box and first box and also drawing arrows. I'm not sure when I'm anchoring to north, why would there be so much mis-match. Code is below:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
  \node [draw=black,rotate=90,anchor=north,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=0.75cm] (io) {I/O interface};
  \node [draw=black,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=0.75cm, right =1cm of io] (io2) {SSD System};
  \node [draw=black,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=0.75cm, below =0.32cm of io2] (io3) {Fuzzy Logic ACC};
  \draw[red,thick,dotted] ($(io2.north west)+(-0.1,0.22)$)  rectangle ($(io3.south east)+(0.1,-0.22)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Any help, suggestions or ideas would be appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: 
With Kevin's answer I'm able to make good progress, this is what I've got so far. I got somewhat arrows drawn, now I need to figure out how to make text and put labels beside I/O interface.

:[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would place the `io` node relative to the `io2`-`io3` block. This way, `io` can be vertically centered relative to the other two nodes.

## Code

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
  \tikzset{
    box/.style={draw=black,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=.75cm},
    >=latex,
  }
  \node(io2)[box]{SSD System};
  \node(io3)[box,below=.32cm of io2]{Fuzzy Logic ACC};
  \draw[red,thick,dotted] ($(io2.north west)+(-0.1,0.22)$) rectangle ($(io3.south east)+(0.1,-0.22)$);  
  \coordinate(mid left)at($(io2.west)!.5!(io3.west)$);
  \node(io)[box,rotate=90,left=1cm of mid left,anchor=center]{I/O interface};

  % drawing arrows
  \path(io.south west)--(io.south east) coordinate[pos=.33](x1) coordinate[pos=.67](x2);
  \draw[->](x2)--+(.2,0);
  \draw[<-](x1)--+(.2,0);

  \path(io2.south west)--(io2.south east) coordinate[pos=.33](y1) coordinate[pos=.67](y2);
  \draw[->](y1)--+(0,-.15);
  \draw[<-](y2)--+(0,-.15);

  \path(io.north east)--(io.north west) coordinate[pos=.2](z1) coordinate[pos=.4](z2) coordinate[pos=.6](z3) coordinate[pos=.8](z4);
  \draw[<-](z1)--+(-.5,0) node[anchor=east]{Distance Sensor};
  \draw[<-](z2)--+(-.5,0) node[anchor=east]{Video Input};
  \draw[<-](z3)--+(-.5,0) node[anchor=east]{Set Speed Limit};
  \draw[->](z4)--+(-.5,0) node[anchor=east]{Factored Acceleration};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to draw arrow from I/O to red dotted block?

Comment: @ShivamKalra: See my updated answer.

Comment: You can also use `fit` for red dotted rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \node [draw=black,rotate=90,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=0.75cm]  (io) {I/O interface};
  \node [xshift=1cm,draw=black, minimum width=3cm,minimum height=0.75cm, below right =0.7cm of io]          (io2) {SSD System};
  \node [draw=black, minimum width=3cm,minimum height=0.75cm, below =0.35cm of io2] (io3) {Fuzzy Logic ACC};
 \draw [line] ([xshift=-0.5cm]io2.south)--([xshift=-0.5cm]io3.north);
 \draw [line] ([xshift=0.5cm]io3.north)--([xshift=0.5cm]io2.south);
  \node [fit=(io2)(io3),  draw,  inner sep=0.5cm](Box){};
  \draw [line] ([shift={(-3cm,1cm)}]io.north) node (a) {Distance center} +(2,0) -- (a-|io.north);
 \draw [line] ([shift={(-3cm,0.5cm)}]io.north) node (b) {Distance Sensor} +(2,0) -- (b-|io.north);
 \draw [line] ([shift={(-3cm,0cm)}]io.north) node (c) {Vedio Input} +(2,0)-- (c-|io.north);
 \draw [line] ([shift={(-3cm,-0.5cm)}]io.north) node (d) {Set Speed Limit} +(2,0)-- (d-|io.north);
 \draw [latex'-] ([shift={(-3cm,-1cm)}]io.north) node (e) {Factored Acceleration} +(2,0)-- (e-|io.north);
  \node[anchor=south,at=(Box.north)]  {ADAS};
\draw [line] ([shift={(0.4,-1cm)}]io.east) node(f){} -- (f-|Box.west){};
\draw [latex'-] ([shift={(0.4,-2cm)}]io.east) node(g){} -- (g-|Box.west){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using `fit` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,calc}
\tikzset{decision/.style = {diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node
                            distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt},
         block/.style    = {rectangle, draw, fill=black!25, text width=5em, text centered, rounded
                            corners, minimum height=4em},
         line/.style     = {draw, -latex'},
         cloud/.style    = {draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm, minimum height=2em}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,font=\small]
        \node [draw=black,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=0.85cm] (io2) {SSD System};
        \node [draw=black,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=0.85cm, below =0.32cm of io2] (io3) {Fuzzy Logic ACC};
        \draw [latex-] ($(io2.south east)!0.33!(io2.south west)$) -- ($(io3.north east)!0.33!(io3.north west)$);
        \draw [-latex] ($(io2.south east)!0.66!(io2.south west)$) -- ($(io3.north east)!0.66!(io3.north west)$);
        \node[fit=(io2) (io3), draw=red, dotted,minimum height=3cm] (fit) {};
        \node[anchor=south] at (fit.north) {ADAS};
        \node [draw=black,rotate=90,anchor=north,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=0.75cm,left=1cm of fit,anchor=south] (io) {I/O interface};
        \draw[-latex] ($(io.south east)!0.3!(io.south west)$) -- ($(fit.north west)!0.3!(fit.south west)$);
        \draw[latex-] ($(io.south east)!0.7!(io.south west)$) -- ($(fit.north west)!0.7!(fit.south west)$);
        \foreach \x/\a in {0.2/2,0.4/4,0.6/6,0.8/8}{
        \coordinate (z\a) at ($(io.north east)!\x!(io.north west)$);
        }
        \draw[latex-](z2)--+(-.5,0) node[anchor=east]{Distance Sensor};
        \draw[latex-](z4)--+(-.5,0) node[anchor=east]{Video Input};
        \draw[latex-](z6)--+(-.5,0) node[anchor=east]{Set Speed Limit};
        \draw[-latex](z8)--+(-.5,0) node[anchor=east,minimum width=3.1cm,align=left]{Factored \\ Acceleration}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was just trying to update my answer using `fit`. But I guess there's no need now `:)`

Comment: @KevinC Ohho!. Sorry Kevin. I think I would have waited :-)